# Closed form solution to $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\exp(-a(n-b)^2)}{n!}$ for $a>0$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I doubt it exists, but I'm looking to find a closed form expression for the series  $$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{\exp(-a(k-b)^2)}{k!}$$ for $a>0$. It appears as an infinite sum of Gaussians with means placed $k$ apart from each other, each weighted by $P(k) \sim \text{Poiss}(\lambda)$. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: If [WolframAlpha doesn't know](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum(k%3D0,infinity,e%5E(-k%5E2)%2Fk!)), I probably don't either.